# How do I join two columns where date from Table A falls in between date from Table B in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following two tables Table A and Table B:

Table A:

```
+-----------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+
|      Date       |     Car      | License_Plate |    Owner    |
+-----------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+
| 1/1/2020 11:51  | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | John Doe    |
| 2/2/2020 12:43  | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | Jane Doe    |
| 3/21/2020 8:14  | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | John Smith  |
| 1/1/2019 10:27  | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | Adam Baker  |
| 7/3/2019 13:39  | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | Clark Davis |
| 9/24/2019 16:48 | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | Frank Evans |
| 2/14/2020 19:53 | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | William Johnson |
+-----------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Table B:

```
+------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
|       Date       | License_Plate | Maintenance_Service_Mileage |
+------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
| 1/14/2020 14:07  | 3892A84       | 5000 miles                  |
| 1/30/2020 17:14  | 3892A84       | 10000 miles                 |
| 2/11/2020 11:45  | 3892A84       | 15000 miles                 |
| 2/28/2020 13:36  | 3892A84       | 20000 miles                 |
| 3/4/2020 15:32   | 3892A84       | 25000 miles                 |
| 3/31/2020 10:24  | 3892A84       | 30000 miles                 |
| 4/16/2020 16:01  | 3892A84       | 35000 miles                 |
| 5/18/2020 14:14  | 3892A84       | 40000 miles                 |
| 1/25/2019 13:11  | 894A839       | 5000 miles                  |
| 6/27/2019 12:44  | 894A839       | 10000 miles                 |
| 9/1/2019 16:17   | 894A839       | 15000 miles                 |
| 10/31/2019 8:59  | 894A839       | 20000 miles                 |
| 11/22/2019 10:55 | 894A839       | 25000 miles                 |
| 12/19/2019 15:41 | 894A839       | 30000 miles                 |
| 1/2/2020 14:22   | 894A839       | 35000 miles                 |
| 2/13/2020 17:42  | 894A839       | 40000 miles                 |
| 3/7/2020 9:14    | 894A839       | 45000 miles                 |
| 4/13/2020 9:58   | 894A839       | 50000 miles                 |
+------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
```

I want to join the two tables by `License_Plate` in a way where the date in Table A and date in Table B fit the following criteria:

1. Date in Table A <= Date in Table B
2. Date in Table B joins to the largest possible date in Table A that fits criteria 1

The resulting table is below:

Resulting Table:

```
+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
|   Owner_Date    |     Car      |      Owner      |   Service_Date   | License_Plate | Maintenance_Service_Mileage |
+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
| 1/1/2020 11:51  | Ford F150    | John Doe        | 1/14/2020 14:07  | 3892A84       | 5000 miles                  |
| 1/1/2020 11:51  | Ford F150    | John Doe        | 1/30/2020 17:14  | 3892A84       | 10000 miles                 |
| 2/2/2020 12:43  | Ford F150    | Jane Doe        | 2/11/2020 11:45  | 3892A84       | 15000 miles                 |
| 2/2/2020 12:43  | Ford F150    | Jane Doe        | 2/28/2020 13:36  | 3892A84       | 20000 miles                 |
| 2/2/2020 12:43  | Ford F150    | Jane Doe        | 3/4/2020 15:32   | 3892A84       | 25000 miles                 |
| 3/21/2020 8:14  | Ford F150    | John Smith      | 3/31/2020 10:24  | 3892A84       | 30000 miles                 |
| 3/21/2020 8:14  | Ford F150    | John Smith      | 4/16/2020 16:01  | 3892A84       | 35000 miles                 |
| 3/21/2020 8:14  | Ford F150    | John Smith      | 5/18/2020 14:14  | 3892A84       | 40000 miles                 |
| 1/1/2019 10:27  | Toyota Camry | Adam Baker      | 1/25/2019 13:11  | 894A839       | 5000 miles                  |
| 1/1/2019 10:27  | Toyota Camry | Adam Baker      | 6/27/2019 12:44  | 894A839       | 10000 miles                 |
| 7/3/2019 13:39  | Toyota Camry | Clark Davis     | 9/1/2019 16:17   | 894A839       | 15000 miles                 |
| 9/24/2019 16:48 | Toyota Camry | Frank Evans     | 10/31/2019 8:59  | 894A839       | 20000 miles                 |
| 9/24/2019 16:48 | Toyota Camry | Frank Evans     | 11/22/2019 10:55 | 894A839       | 25000 miles                 |
| 9/24/2019 16:48 | Toyota Camry | Frank Evans     | 12/19/2019 15:41 | 894A839       | 30000 miles                 |
| 9/24/2019 16:48 | Toyota Camry | Frank Evans     | 1/2/2020 14:22   | 894A839       | 35000 miles                 |
| 9/24/2019 16:48 | Toyota Camry | Frank Evans     | 2/13/2020 17:42  | 894A839       | 40000 miles                 |
| 2/14/2020 19:53 | Toyota Camry | William Johnson | 3/7/2020 9:14    | 894A839       | 45000 miles                 |
| 2/14/2020 19:53 | Toyota Camry | William Johnson | 4/13/2020 9:58   | 894A839       | 50000 miles                 |
+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
```

Can someone show me how to do this in Oracle SQL?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle 12C supports lateral joins which make this pretty simple:

```
select b.*, a.*
from b left join lateral
     (select a.*
      from a
      where a.License_Plate = b.License_Plate and a.date <= b.date
      order by a.date desc
      fetch first 1 row only
     ) a;
```

An alternative method is to use a `join` -- but to calculate starting and ending dates:

```
select a.*, b.*
from b left join
     (select a.*,
             lead(date) over (partition by License_Plate order by date) as next_date
      from a
     ) a
     on b.License_Plate = a.License_Plate and
        b.date >= a.date and
        (b.date <= a.next_date or a.next_date is null);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply Gordon! One question. Is there a more efficient method from the two solutions you provided?

Comment: @DanielLee . . . You would actually need to try them out on your data.  With an index on `a(license_place, date)`, I would speculate that the first would be faster, but that is just a guess.

Comment: Another question @GordonLinoff about your sql query. Regarding your second solution, why are we doing a `b left join a` instead of `a left join b`?

Comment: @DanielLee . . . My reading of the question seemed to suggest that you wanted all rows in `b`.  Perhaps the tables are backward.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I want all the rows in `b` in the resulting table. Is `b lef join a` the way to ensure that all rows in `b` will appear in the resulting table? That is, what if I just do `a join b`. Wouldn't that also result in all rows? The assumption that I have for the tables is that there will always be a matching license plate between the two tables. Also, for each license plate, table A will have the earliest date for the given license plate for the two tables. Given these 2 assumptions, do we still need to do `b left join a` or can we do another join?

Comment: `b left join a` keeps all rows in `b` and then matching columns in `a`.  `a left join b` keeps all rows in `a` with matching columns in `b`.