# How do I join two columns where date from Table A falls in between date from Table B in Oracle SQL (Part 2)?

Tags: oracle

This question is a modification from a previous question I wrote:

[How do I join two columns where date from Table A falls in between date from Table B in Oracle SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62868188/how-do-i-join-two-columns-where-date-from-table-a-falls-in-between-date-from-tab)

@GordonLinoff has helped me answer the question satisfactorily.

Now, I need help with a tweak to the previous problem. The modification from the previous question is that I added two more rows to Table A: rows corresponding to `Joe Bryant` and `Jennifer Smith`.

As a result, I have the following two tables Table A and Table B:

Table A:

```
+-----------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+
|      Date       |     Car      | License_Plate |    Owner    |
+-----------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+
| 1/1/2020 11:51  | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | John Doe    |
| 2/2/2020 12:43  | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | Jane Doe    |
| 3/21/2020 8:14  | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | John Smith  |
| 6/2/2020 13:59  | Ford F150    | 3892A84       | Joe Bryant  |
| 1/1/2019 10:27  | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | Adam Baker  |
| 7/3/2019 13:39  | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | Clark Davis |
| 9/24/2019 16:48 | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | Frank Evans |
| 2/14/2020 19:53 | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | William Johnson |
| 5/22/2020 9:44  | Toyota Camry | 894A839       | Jennifer Smith |
+-----------------+--------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Table B:

```
+------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
|       Date       | License_Plate | Maintenance_Service_Mileage |
+------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
| 1/14/2020 14:07  | 3892A84       | 5000 miles                  |
| 1/30/2020 17:14  | 3892A84       | 10000 miles                 |
| 2/11/2020 11:45  | 3892A84       | 15000 miles                 |
| 2/28/2020 13:36  | 3892A84       | 20000 miles                 |
| 3/4/2020 15:32   | 3892A84       | 25000 miles                 |
| 3/31/2020 10:24  | 3892A84       | 30000 miles                 |
| 4/16/2020 16:01  | 3892A84       | 35000 miles                 |
| 5/18/2020 14:14  | 3892A84       | 40000 miles                 |
| 1/25/2019 13:11  | 894A839       | 5000 miles                  |
| 6/27/2019 12:44  | 894A839       | 10000 miles                 |
| 9/1/2019 16:17   | 894A839       | 15000 miles                 |
| 10/31/2019 8:59  | 894A839       | 20000 miles                 |
| 11/22/2019 10:55 | 894A839       | 25000 miles                 |
| 12/19/2019 15:41 | 894A839       | 30000 miles                 |
| 1/2/2020 14:22   | 894A839       | 35000 miles                 |
| 2/13/2020 17:42  | 894A839       | 40000 miles                 |
| 3/7/2020 9:14    | 894A839       | 45000 miles                 |
| 4/13/2020 9:58   | 894A839       | 50000 miles                 |
+------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
```

I want to join the two tables by `License_Plate` in a way where the date in Table A and date in Table B fit the following criteria:

1. `Date` in Table A <= `Date` in Table B
2. `Date` in Table B joins to the largest possible date in Table A that fits criteria 1
3. In the case where row in Table A does not have a matching row in Table B, then row in Table A should join with the row that has the largest `Date` in Table B while still joining by `License_Plate`.

The resulting table is below:

Resulting Table:

```
+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
|   Owner_Date    |     Car      |      Owner      |   Service_Date   | License_Plate | Maintenance_Service_Mileage |
+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
| 1/1/2020 11:51  | Ford F150    | John Doe        | 1/14/2020 14:07  | 3892A84       | 5000 miles                  |
| 1/1/2020 11:51  | Ford F150    | John Doe        | 1/30/2020 17:14  | 3892A84       | 10000 miles                 |
| 2/2/2020 12:43  | Ford F150    | Jane Doe        | 2/11/2020 11:45  | 3892A84       | 15000 miles                 |
| 2/2/2020 12:43  | Ford F150    | Jane Doe        | 2/28/2020 13:36  | 3892A84       | 20000 miles                 |
| 2/2/2020 12:43  | Ford F150    | Jane Doe        | 3/4/2020 15:32   | 3892A84       | 25000 miles                 |
| 3/21/2020 8:14  | Ford F150    | John Smith      | 3/31/2020 10:24  | 3892A84       | 30000 miles                 |
| 3/21/2020 8:14  | Ford F150    | John Smith      | 4/16/2020 16:01  | 3892A84       | 35000 miles                 |
| 3/21/2020 8:14  | Ford F150    | John Smith      | 5/18/2020 14:14  | 3892A84       | 40000 miles                 |
| 6/2/2020 13:59  | Ford F150    | Joe Bryant      | 5/18/2020 14:14  | 3892A84       | 40000 miles                 |
| 1/1/2019 10:27  | Toyota Camry | Adam Baker      | 1/25/2019 13:11  | 894A839       | 5000 miles                  |
| 1/1/2019 10:27  | Toyota Camry | Adam Baker      | 6/27/2019 12:44  | 894A839       | 10000 miles                 |
| 7/3/2019 13:39  | Toyota Camry | Clark Davis     | 9/1/2019 16:17   | 894A839       | 15000 miles                 |
| 9/24/2019 16:48 | Toyota Camry | Frank Evans     | 10/31/2019 8:59  | 894A839       | 20000 miles                 |
| 9/24/2019 16:48 | Toyota Camry | Frank Evans     | 11/22/2019 10:55 | 894A839       | 25000 miles                 |
| 9/24/2019 16:48 | Toyota Camry | Frank Evans     | 12/19/2019 15:41 | 894A839       | 30000 miles                 |
| 9/24/2019 16:48 | Toyota Camry | Frank Evans     | 1/2/2020 14:22   | 894A839       | 35000 miles                 |
| 9/24/2019 16:48 | Toyota Camry | Frank Evans     | 2/13/2020 17:42  | 894A839       | 40000 miles                 |
| 2/14/2020 19:53 | Toyota Camry | William Johnson | 3/7/2020 9:14    | 894A839       | 45000 miles                 |
| 2/14/2020 19:53 | Toyota Camry | William Johnson | 4/13/2020 9:58   | 894A839       | 50000 miles                 |
| 5/22/2020 9:44  | Toyota Camry | Jennifer Smith  | 4/13/2020 9:58   | 894A839       | 50000 miles                 |
+-----------------+--------------+-----------------+------------------+---------------+-----------------------------+
```

Can someone show me how to do this in Oracle SQL?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this:

```
with a as (
            select '1/1/2020 11:51' as date_a,  'Ford F150' as car,     '3892A84' as license_plate, 'John Doe' as name from dual
            union
            select '2/2/2020 12:43' as date_a,  'Ford F150' as car,     '3892A84' as license_plate, 'Jane Doe'       from dual
            union
            select '3/21/2020 8:14' as date_a,  'Ford F150' as car,     '3892A84' as license_plate, 'John Smith'     from dual
            union
            select '6/2/2020 13:59' as date_a,  'Ford F150' as car,     '3892A84' as license_plate, 'Joe Bryant'     from dual
            union
            select '1/1/2019 10:27' as date_a,  'Toyota Camry' as car, '894A839' as license_plate, 'Adam Baker'      from dual
            union
            select '7/3/2019 13:39' as date_a,  'Toyota Camry' as car, '894A839' as license_plate, 'Clark Davis'     from dual
            union
            select '9/24/2019 16:48' as date_a, 'Toyota Camry' as car, '894A839' as license_plate, 'Frank Evans'     from dual
            union
            select '2/14/2020 19:53' as date_a, 'Toyota Camry' as car, '894A839' as license_plate, 'William Johnson' from dual
            union
            select '5/22/2020 9:44' as date_a,  'Toyota Camry' as car, '894A839' as license_plate, 'Jennifer Smith'  from dual
                )
        ,b as(
            select '1/14/2020 14:07 ' as date_b,'3892A84' as License_plate, '5000 miles ' as maintence_service_mile from dual union
            select '1/30/2020 17:14 ' as date_b,'3892A84' as License_plate, '10000 miles' as maintence_service_mile from dual union
            select '2/11/2020 11:45 ' as date_b,'3892A84' as License_plate, '15000 miles' as maintence_service_mile from dual union
            select '2/28/2020 13:36 ' as date_b,'3892A84' as License_plate, '20000 miles' as maintence_service_mile from dual union
            select '3/4/2020 15:32  ' as date_b,'3892A84' as License_plate, '25000 miles' as maintence_service_mile from dual union
            select '3/31/2020 10:24 ' as date_b,'3892A84' as License_plate, '30000 miles' as maintence_service_mile from dual union
            select '4/16/2020 16:01 ' as date_b,'3892A84' as License_plate, '35000 miles' as maintence_service_mile from dual union
            select '5/18/2020 14:14 ' as date_b,'3892A84' as License_plate, '40000 miles' as maintence_service_mile from dual union
            select '1/25/2019 13:11 ' as date_b,'894A839' as License_plate, '5000 miles ' as maintence_service_mile from dual union
            select '6/27/2019 12:44 ' as date_b,'894A839' as License_plate, '10000 miles' as maintence_service_mile from dual union
            select '9/1/2019 16:17  ' as date_b,'894A839' as License_plate, '15000 miles' as maintence_service_mile from dual union
            select '10/31/2019 8:59 ' as date_b,'894A839' as License_plate, '20000 miles' as maintence_service_mile from dual union
            select '11/22/2019 10:55' as date_b,'894A839' as License_plate, '25000 miles' as maintence_service_mile from dual union
            select '12/19/2019 15:41' as date_b,'894A839' as License_plate, '30000 miles' as maintence_service_mile from dual union
            select '1/2/2020 14:22  ' as date_b,'894A839' as License_plate, '35000 miles' as maintence_service_mile from dual union
            select '2/13/2020 17:42 ' as date_b,'894A839' as License_plate, '40000 miles' as maintence_service_mile from dual union
            select '3/7/2020 9:14   ' as date_b,'894A839' as License_plate, '45000 miles' as maintence_service_mile from dual union
            select '4/13/2020 9:58  ' as date_b,'894A839' as License_plate, '50000 miles' as maintence_service_mile from dual
        
            )
                SELECT subq.date_a AS OWNER_DATE,subq.CAR AS CAR,NAME AS OWNER,B.date_B AS SERVICE_DATE,B.LICENSE_PLATE,b.maintence_service_mile FROM(
                SELECT LICENSE_PLATE,name,CAR,date_a FROM(
                SELECT LICENSE_PLATE,name,CAR,a.date_a,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name,LICENSE_PLATE ORDER BY to_date(a.date_a,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')) AS R FROM A )
                WHERE R=1) SUBQ
                INNER JOIN B ON b.license_plate = SUBQ.LICENSE_PLATE AND subq.date_a < B.date_B
                ORDER BY CAR,NAME,to_date(date_a,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'),b.maintence_service_mile;
```

Still I believe your result table is not completed or the criteria you want to apply is not clear enough.

Comment: Hey @KOBER. Thanks for helping me out. I noticed that the result from your proposed solution does not match with the result I am hoping for. Please let me know how I can clarify the question to help you understand better what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Hey @DanielLee please proceed with the clarification, once I red it or any other member we could help you better